# MySQL: refer to SELECT subquery alias in WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there an easier way to write an SQL query if I want to refer to SELECT subquery in WHERE part of the query?

This is my code:

```
SELECT
    SUM(x) AS test,
    (SELECT SUM(y) FROM other_table) AS sub_test,
    (test + sub_test) AS total_sum
FROM my_database
WHERE
    test <> 0 AND sub_test <> 0
```

The code is just for illustration :) It works if I put the subquery instead of alias like:

```
SELECT
    SUM(x) AS test,
    (SELECT SUM(y) FROM other_table) AS sub_test,
    (SUM(x) + (SELECT SUM(y) FROM other_table)) AS total_sum
FROM my_database
WHERE
    SUM(x) <> 0 AND (SELECT SUM(y) FROM other_table) <> 0
```

But writing the whole subquery xx times is a bit awkward since the subquery is not just a plain "SELECT (SUM(..))"... If I want to change something in subquery I have to change it xx times and hope that I changed all of them..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `HAVING` clause over `WHERE`. And
Use user variables on the values just computed on the precious column expressions.

```
SELECT
    @sx:=SUM(x) AS test,
    (SELECT @sy:=SUM(y) FROM other_table) AS sub_test,
    (@sx + @sy) AS total_sum
FROM my_database
HAVING
    -- SUM(x) <> 0 AND (SELECT SUM(y) FROM other_table) <> 0
    test <> 0 AND sub_test <> 0
```

Comment: Call me a noob but what does this do "@sx:="?

Comment: It is user variable. It allows you to buffer the value calculated in the previous expression and use the same in next expression. So that you can avoid repeating the same expression.

Comment: Thanks! You just opened a whole new world of MySQL querys for me :) And thank you for the answer - it works great!

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        SUM(x) AS test,
        (SELECT SUM(y) FROM other_table) AS sub_test,
        (SUM(x) + (SELECT SUM(y) FROM other_table)) AS total_sum
    FROM my_database
) AS tbl
WHERE tbl.test <> 0 AND tbl.total_sum <> 0
```

Or you can also do this:

```
SELECT
    tbl.test,
    tbl.sub_test,
    (tbl.sub_test+tbl.test) AS total_sum
FROM
(
    SELECT
        SUM(x) AS test,
        (SELECT SUM(y) FROM other_table) AS sub_test
    FROM my_database
) AS tbl
WHERE tbl.test <> 0 AND (tbl.sub_test+tbl.test) <> 0
```